# The Proof environment, when I justify a step show does not respect the margins of my document

Tags: math-mode

[image]

That this problem as seen in the image. When I use the environment does not respect me proff margins in my document, how you fix it ?. Thank you

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  more details, please, preferably with a small compilable example that shows exactly the input for this visual.  it does not involve any bibliography (your `biblatex` tag), but some math display environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal fully compilable code?

Comment: `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` is not a real word so tex can not hyphenate it if you entered it as text, and it never hyphenates mathematics, so with that input there is nothing it can do. You would need to split it by hand but with just an image shown it is hard to guess what changes are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX will only introduce line-breaks where it deems it necessary, and `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` does not represent a word that can by properly hyphenated.

If you wish to comment on lines within your proof, set the comment in a `t`op-aligned box of fixed width. Below I've used a `\parbox` of width 20em (adjust as needed). You can also use a `tabular` or some other construction, if needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{showframe} Just to show the text frame

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \qquad \parbox[t]{20em}{\raggedright\strut
    Here is a lengthy description or comment that relates to 
    the expression on the right.\strut} \\
    &= d
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```